# Show leaflet markers that falls inside mapbounds,based on geocode location entered , from database

Tags: leaflet, pyqt5, openstreetmap, python-3.7

I have a GUI application where data from my database are displayed on a table and also displayed as markers on leaflet map . I have added the Geocode ( L.Control.geocoder() ) function into my application , and want to now show the markers, from my database , that fits into the map bounds of where my Geocode location is.

I have read up on map.toBBoxString() and map.getBounds() from leaflet documentation which is what I think I would need to make a comparison and write a query for my database data to display in the 'Geo-coded' location entered . My problem is I don't know how to get the actual values and make a comparison for my Python query  . Below is my search button part of code that connects to function  to display data entered from user on table and map .

```
def search_all(self):


        print ('Searching All...')
        looking = str(self.lookall.text())       
        if looking == "":
            QMessageBox.about(self, "No Info ", " Please enter value ")         
        else :

            conn = #connection to DB

            cursor = conn.cursor()        
            query = "SELECT*FROM CT_ALL_F WHERE Lic_no LIKE  '%s' OR Licensee LIKE '%s' OR FREQ LIKE '%s' OR Power LIKE '%s' OR Installation_address LIKE '%s' OR Business_address LIKE '%s' OR Tel LIKE '%s' " %('%'+looking+'%','%'+looking+'%','%'+looking+'%','%'+looking+'%','%'+looking+'%','%'+looking+'%','%'+looking+'%')        
            cursor.execute(query)    
            results = cursor.fetchall()

            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)            
            for row_number, row_data in enumerate(results):                
                self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)                
                for column_number, data in enumerate (row_data):                                        
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number,column_number,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))                    
                    pass
                pass

                coordinates = []

                for result in results:        
                    coordinates.append((result[5], result[6] ,(result[0], result[1],result[2],result[3],result[4])))


                lat_center = sum([coordinate[0] for coordinate in coordinates]) / len(coordinates)
                lng_center = sum([coordinate[1] for coordinate in coordinates]) / len(coordinates)

                html = """
                        <!DOCTYPE html>
                        <html>
                        <head>
                        <style type="text/css">
                                html { height: 100%; }
                                body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
                                #mapid { height: 100% }
                        </style>
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin=""/>
                        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw==" crossorigin=""></script>

                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.css" />
                        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js"></script>


                        </head>
                        <body>
                        <div id="mapDiv" style="width:100%; height:100%"</div>
                        <script>

                        """

                html += "var map = L.map('mapDiv').setView([{lat}, {lng}], 10);".format(lat=lat_center, lng=lng_center)                
                html += """
                        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.icasa.org.za/">ICASA</a> <br> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
                        }).addTo(map);

                        """

                for latitude, longitude , frequency in coordinates:

                    html += "var marker = L.marker([{lat}, {lng}]);\n ".format(lat=latitude, lng=longitude)                   
                    html += "var popupLocation1 = new L.LatLng({lat}, {lng});".format(lat=latitude, lng=longitude )                    
                    html += """var popupContent1 = ("License number : {freq}<br>Licensee: {dek}<br>Frequency : {lek}<br>Power : {sek}<br>Location : {mek}<br>"),""".format(freq=frequency[0],dek=frequency[1],lek=frequency[2],sek=frequency[3],mek=frequency[4])
                    html += "popup1 = new L.Popup();"
                    html += "popup1.setLatLng(popupLocation1);"
                    html += "popup1.setContent(popupContent1);"
                    html+= "marker.bindPopup(popupContent1);"
                    html += "map.addLayer(popup1).addLayer(marker);"

                    html += "L.Control.geocoder().addTo(map);</script> </body> </html>"
                self.view.setHtml(html)
```

I expect to see markers from my DB that sit inside the mapbounds of map , after geocode location entered , displayed on my leaflet map

[image: My Sample DB][image]

Comment: Could you explain me better, I don't understand what you want to do. In addition to sharing the .db

Comment: I basically want to achieve following : User enters a  certain Location on the Map with the Leaflet Geocode function . The Map then go's to that location . In addition to that , I want my markers displayed that fit within the map bounds . Thus if my Lat Long info in DB falls within map bounds , display it on map . I will re-edit my Question to include DB or add picture

Comment: I have edited my question to explain a bit better

Comment: So I made a small bit of progress and hopefully somebody  can help me jump-start it further on . So I pip installed the geocoder   python module . Now I am able to easily see and retrieve my map bounding box co-ordinates . g.northeast[0] , g.northeast[1] , g.southwest[0] , g.southwest[1] .

Comment: @eyllanesc So , i think i only have one more hurdle to get this done . Only one problem . I have a Ms Access database , with my lat/longs indicated  as double(datatype) . My leaflet map lat/longs are indicated as float in Python code . I get an error when i try to write a comparison query between the map and db  lat and longs thou. i.e a data mismatch type error

Comment: I changed the datatype from my Ms Access DB to short text  which enabled me to write a query with the bounding box co-ordinates i got from geocoder . This worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the datatype from my Ms Access DB to short text which enabled me to write a comparison  query from my db results with my bounding box co-ordinates I got from geocoder . This worked